# PHP Artisan migrate fails

Tags: laravel, composer-php, migrate

**This problem has been solved. Check my post below**

I have just installed a fresh Laravel 5.4 project.

As i'm following Jeffrey Way's Laravel from scratch tutorial i get the following errors when i want to migrate my database:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already
  exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment pr
  imary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `passwo
  rd` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` tim
  estamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate
  utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
```

-

```
[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already
  exists
```

Like i said, it's a fresh installation and i don't know how to fix this. Does anyone of you know?

Thanks in advance!

@ian,

I followed the instructions you gave me but now i get this error:

```
    [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too l
  ong; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_em
  ail_unique`(`email`))
```

-

```
  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too l
  ong; max key length is 767 bytes
```

**How to solve this issue:**

This is how i did this, thanks to Ian:

1. delete database and create a new one
2. Update env file with new database credentials
3. Go to **App->Providers->AppServiceProvider.php**
4. Add `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` to the boot function
5. make sure to add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` on the top of the file.
6. Migrate the database and the problem is solved!

Comment: Drop and recreate the database, as the error states the table in the database already exists.

Comment: Check my editted post

Comment: What exactly did you edit, I don't see any difference between this version on the last?

Comment: Check again. Sorry i'm a bit slow this morning haha

Comment: Check your .env file and see on which DB are you migrating! Maybe you are migrating to the same DB that you have used before!!!

Comment: @lewis4u I'm not trying to migrate to the db i've used before. I created a new database and i'm using that one.

Comment: I have added in answer below, it all boils down to the encoding it seems for your second issue refer to https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error for a more indepth explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second error you come across regarding key lengths is a new change in Laravel 5.4. When using the utf8mb4 encoding, varchar fields can only be a max of 194.

You will need to head into your migrations, alter the size of each occurrence of string() and add a length. Optionally you can change your database encoding back to UTF8, however utf8mb4 allows the use of storing emojis.

You can refer to https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error for more information

Comment: Thanks Ian, this solved the problem. I've editted my post with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

When doing `php artisan migrate` the database can't have the same table name like in migration (except if you are adding just another field in that table)

You must delete all of your tables (drop) and then run `php artisan migrate` again.